# AWS devops engineer question. Which architecture will meet these requirements with the least amount of configuration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-devops

I have a doubt regarding this question of the AWS devops engineer certification:

> A Devops Engineer is architecting a continuous development strategy for a company's software as a Service web application running on AWS. For application and security reasons, users subscribing to this application are distributed across multiple Application Load Balancers each of which has a dedicated Auto Scaling group fleet of Amazon EC2 instances. The application must trigger a simultaneous deployment to all ALBs, Auto Scaling groups, and EC2 fleets. Which architecture will meet these requirements with the least amount of configuration?

> A- Create a single AWS Code Pipeline pipeline that deploys the application in in parallel using unique AWS CodeDeploy applications and deployment groups created for each ALB-AutoScaling group pair.

> B- Create a single AWS CodePipeline pipeline that deploys the application using a single AWS CodeDeplot application and single deployment group.

> C- Create a single AWS CodePipeline that deploys the application in parallel using a single AWS CodeDeploy application and unique deployment group for each ALB-AUtoscaling group pair

> D- Create an AWS CodePipeline pipeline for each ALB-Auto Scaling group pair that deploys the application using an AWS CodeDeploy application and deployment group created for the same ALB-Auto scaling group pair

Answer (score 1):

Each possible answer is reviewed:

A- it can be possible but it says with the least amount of configuration. Simultaneous deployments can be achieved only with one deployment group per ALB-ASG

B- it cannot be used in a single deployment group for multiples pair ALB-ASG

C- it seems to be the right one

D- it is not needed to create a pipeline for each pair.

Answer (score 1):

C -  It seems to be the right one

This option allows you to use a single CodePipeline while still deploying in parallel to different ALB-AutoScaling group pairs. Using a unique deployment group for each pair ensures that you can customize the deployment settings for each specific group, meeting the application and security requirements. This approach minimizes the overall configuration complexity compared to creating separate pipelines for each pair (option D).